# Trouble understanding instance variable

Tags: c++

Here is the definition:

In object-oriented programming with classes, an instance variable is a variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable) // I get this part

, for which each object of the class has a separate copy. // This part I don't get.

How can an object have a seperate copy? a seperate copy of what?

Sorry for asking basic questions, I'm still a noob.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[COMMENT ANSWER]**
An instance variable is a variable that has an instance for each object declared where a class variable is a single member variable for which there is only one for all objects declared of that type. Class variable uses the keyword static, where an instance variable does not!

**[ORIGINAL]**
When you define a class, it has member declarations.

An object isn't truly instantiated (or given memory space) until a variable of that class type is defined.

If you then define two of that class type, those objects are given their own memory spaces, and indeed each member of each object has its own memory (thus 2 separate instantiations of that object).

Now each grouping of data (within the objects) can and really is manipulated separately.

Class Variable:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable

Instance Variable:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable

Comment: Thanks, but whats the difference between instance variable and normal variable within a class?

Comment: A good example of a class variable is a counter, which adds 1 for each instance of a class, and can later be checked to see how many objects were instantiated.

Comment: @DanT - Great Example Comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two objects, each object will have its own copy of the instance variable. I.e. `a.x` will be different from `b.x`, even if you give them the same value.

Comment: So how do you create one and what is the difference between the instance variable and a normal class variable?

Thanks for the fast answer

Comment: I think it's just a difference of nomenclature, although class variables would include `static` members while instance variables would not.

Answer (score 0):

I made another of my terrible etch-a-sketches, and just had to burn your eyes with it. If it clears up any understanding issues, great!

[image: Class member relationships]

So, we have a class, call it `Foo`. `Foo` has some static members, as shown:
`x`, `y`, `z`

At the top, you see non-object access. This means that we can access these static members without an object. In fact, an object doesn't even have to be created before accessing them because they exist before `main` starts.

```
struct Foo {
    static int x, y, z;
};

int Foo::x = 3;
int Foo::y = 1;
int Foo::z = 8;

int main() {
    std::cout << Foo::y;
    Foo::x = 6;
}
```

Next, we have other circles containing two objects' instance members:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    Foo (int a2, int b2, int c2) 
        : a (a2), b (b2), c (c2){}
};

int main() {
    Foo obj1 (6, 9, 10);
    Foo obj2 (3, 2, 4);

    std::cout << obj1.a; //outputs 6
    std::cout << obj2.a; //outputs 3 - different

    obj1.z = 100;
    std::cout << obj2.z; //outputs 100 - same
    std::cout << Foo::z; //outputs 100
}
```

We can also put in member functions and static functions to access variables:

```
struct Foo {
    int getA() const {return a;}
    void setA (int newA) {a = newA;}

    static int getX() const {return x;}
    static void setY (int newY) {return y;}
    static void setB (int newB) {
        b = newB; //error: static functions can't access instance members
    }
}

int main() {
    Foo obj1 (6, 9, 10);

    std::cout << obj1.getX(); //outputs 3
    Foo::setY (5);

    obj1.setA (98);
    std::cout << obj1.getA(); //outputs 98
}
```

To recap:

- Each object can access its own instance members. One object's instance members do not affect the other (unless they are meant to, such as a reference).
- Both objects share the same static member pool. This pool is created, and can be manipulated before any objects are created, using `Foo::` syntax, or after, using `obj1.` or `obj2.` syntax. Changing a static member somewhere affects all cases.
- To control use of these members, make them private and provide access functions. Note that a static function cannot access an instance member. The function could be used without any objects being created, so what's it supposed to do with the instance member? It doesn't have a specific object's pool of instance objects to change!
- To elaborate on the last point, member functions get an implicit `this` argument passed to them, which tells them what variable to modify when you do. `a = newA;` is actually equivalent to `this->a = newA;`. Static member functions, however, do not get a `this` argument, so there's no way to know which object to modify.